# StreamingResponseBody body not executing body returning immeditly - but Rest API still in the process of downloading

Tags: spring-boot, response-entity, streamingresponsebody

I have the below code - after executing below code the client getting immediate response with blank zip file (with out having list of files) , however the StreamingResponseBody
Still executing by reading file by file and writing into output stream - so in client i see only a zip file with no files on it - please let me know how can i fix this issue

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/all", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> documentDownloadAll(@RequestBody MetadataParams metadataParams) {
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<File> documentList = reading list of files here ;
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {try {
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
            try {
                Collection<CompletableFuture<Map<String, byte[]>>> results = new ArrayList<>();
                int i = 0;
                for (File document : documentList) {
                    CompletableFuture<Map<String, byte[]>> completableFuture = fileNetService.downloadDocumentAsyn(document, i++);
                    if (completableFuture != null) {
                        results.add(completableFuture);
                    }
                }
                results.forEach(result -> {
                    result.join();
                });

                log.info("Before iteration");
                for (CompletableFuture<Map<String, byte[]>> mapCompletableFuture : results) {

                    if (mapCompletableFuture != null && mapCompletableFuture.get() != null) {
                        String fileName = null;
                        byte[] fileContent = null;
                        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> map : mapCompletableFuture.get().entrySet()) {
                            fileName = map.getKey();
                            fileContent = map.getValue();
                        }
                        try {
                            log.info("File Name ---------------> {}", fileName);
                            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
                            zos.write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);
                            zos.closeEntry();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                log.info("End Zip");
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }};
        //write(outputStream, documentList);
        log.info("Total time taken : {}", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.bin")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(responseBody);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
       return new ResponseEntity("Error while downloading ZIP file", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

@Async("taskExecutorDoc")
public CompletableFuture<Map<String, byte[]>> downloadDocument(File path) {

    try {
        log.info("----------------------------------------------------->{}", i);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path.toAbsolutePath());
        Map<String, byte[]> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        fileMap.put(i + "_" + path.getFileName(), data);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(fileMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Curl Command:

```
curl -v --trace-time -X 'POST' -o downloadal.zip  'http://localhost:8898/download/all' -H 'Content-type: application/json' --max-time 9000
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but you close the entry but not the zip file in the end
You did - `zos.closeEntry();`
But you also need - `zos.close();`
After adding all the entries

Comment: thank you for response, i have added that too, but same problme